# Printing file prints nothing before truncating and rewriting

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I'm currently working my way through Learning Python the Hard Way and I've got a little bit stuck on a modification I wanted to make on exercise 16.

So, this is my code:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename,'w+')

#Print contents ## WHY WONT THIS WORK??
print "This was inside your file %r:" % filename
target.seek(0)
print target.read()
```

This is where my problem is. The `print` function above does not print the file, rather just gives a blank line. The rest of the code follows below and as you will see there is a second `print` that works fine.

```
print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."
target.write(("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n") % (line1, line2, line3))

#This print does work
target.seek(0)
print target.read()

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use [Python2.x as a beginner](https://pythonclock.org/)? And FWIW, SOpython is [not really fond of Learn Python The Hard Way](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file in a write mode (`'w'` or `'w+'`), python will truncate the file (or create it if it doesn't already exist).

Instead open the file in read/append mode for reading and writing (`'r+'` or `'a+'`), this won't truncate the file and still allow you to both read and write to it.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/3270037) provides a useful flow chart which shows which open modes should be used under what circumstances.

---

Because in your initial code the file was already empty, your `truncate` didn't do anything.

Because of this, when you've updated your code to use `'a+'` or `'r+'` you'll need to update your `truncate`.

`truncate(size)` will truncate the file to the file to the cursors current position (or at most `size` if it is present), so before truncating move the cursor to the beginning for the file again with `target.seek(0)`.

Comment: Thanks mate, does this mean that in my original script this:  
  
    print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"  
    target.truncate()  
<br/>
wasn't actually necessary?
  
When changing it to 'r+' or 'a+', while the $print target.read() function works, the truncate no longer does.. Is there a way to have both? ie read before truncate?

Comment: Makes sense - good to know truncate also uses a cursor position. thanks.